# Pivot Chart/Pivot Table blank/missing data to hide on table

Tags: database, charts, pivot, pivot-table

I hope everybody is well!

Quick question I have concerning Pivot Tables and Pivot Charts. I have quite a quantity of data that I am trying to put into a Pivot Chart, however it also creates space for data that is blank and therefore make the pivot chart very small and hard to read. I've been trying to find a solution for my problem for quite some time and wasn't able to find anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8FQP.png)

What I would like to achieve not to have the data that is blank showing in the pivot chart.

Thank you !

Comment: How about uploading a higher resolution picture. I can't see what's going on in that one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the picture with a better resolution. Due to the huge amount of data I need to illustrate, it's not really clear. My goal is to make it clearer by removing the data that have no value. It appears that space is taken in the chart for variables that have no value in specific months.
What I mean is that I only want to show data that has value in the graph; therefore a way clearer and fuller chart.